# Angular 4/5/6 Progressive JSON objects loading

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I am having hard time implementing progressive data loading with the latest Angular HttpClient. So, I need to make an http request to a node express server and the server should start sending JSON objects back to the client as they become available. So far I've got node.js express server sending back objects like this

```
response.chunkedEncoding = true;
response.contentType('application/json');
response.write(JSON.stringify({ title: 'My JSON object 1'}));
...
response.write(JSON.stringify({ title: 'My JSON object 2'}));
```

at the end of the session

```
response.end();
```

Everything seems to be working fine as I could see progress loading in chrome if I hit the server URL.

Now in Angular client the maximum I can get is number of bytes received by each of server's  response.write

```
this.http.request('GET', 'http://myapiaddress', {params: params, observe: 
        'events', reportProgress: true})
      map(res => console.log('map ', res)),
      catchError(this.processError())
)
.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('subscribe ', event);
});
```

Console output looks like this:

```
map  {type: 0}
subscribe  undefined
map  HttpHeaderResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://myapiaddress", ok: true, …}
subscribe  undefined
map  {type: 3, loaded: 139}
map  {type: 3, loaded: 140}
```

and then after response.end(); is called I am getting a JSON parser error. The JSON parser error is understandable. It's because two JSON objects don't make array on its own. So when HttpClient tries to combine everything in final result it cannot parse the result. But I don't want the final result. I need JSON object on client side as they become available.
If I specify in 'observe:' anything else other then 'events' (like 'response' or 'body') I don't get any progress at all.

What is the correct way of dealing with such scenario? How could I access response body during progress events?

Answer (score 0):

Try `subscribe(event=>` to be `subscribe(event:any=>console.log(event)` or `subscribe((event:any)=>console.lo(event)`